# Как изменить значение списка

Tags: java, android

Есть класс

```
public class MarkerData {

    double latitue,longitude;
    String title,status;
    LatLng lng;
    int number;
 public MarkerData(double longitude, double latitue, String title, LatLng lng, String status, int number) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitue = latitue;
        this.title = title;
        this.lng = lng;
        this.status = status;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public LatLng getLng() {
        return lng;
    }



    public double getLatitue() {
        return latitue;
    }

    public void setLatitue(double latitue) {
        this.latitue = latitue;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

Бросил его в список

```
  ArrayList<MarkerData> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
 latlngs.add(new MarkerData(0,0,"my first",lng(0,0),null,null));
```

Хочу изменить значение latlngs Как  это сделать .Хочу именно изменить значение  0 эелемента  сделать его my second title

Comment: правильно я понимаю, что вы хотите получить первый элемент списка и поменять в нём Title? если да, то вызовите сперва `MarkerData markerData = latlngs.get(0);` а затем `markerData.setTitle("my second title");`

Comment: @RafaelOsipov а нельзя както через latlngs.set * потому что вдруг мне понадобится изнметь 100 элементов

Comment: Можно так: `latlngs.get(0).setTitle("my second title");` в конструкции `get(0)` вместо `0` используйте переменную в цикле, например `get(index)` и всё.

Comment: @Так я также хотел делать не сработало .Пищет 2 аргумент не Стринг .хз пойду разбираться )спасибо!

Comment: покажите код, который не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменить значения (свойства) элементов списка довольно просто.

Допустим ваш список объявлен как:

```
ArrayList<MarkerData> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Тогда, если надо поменять свойства во всех элементах массива, делаем так:

```
// во всех объектах, сохранённых в списке поменяет title на "my second title"
for (MarkerData markerData:latlngs) {
         markerData.setTitle("my second title");
}
```

Если надо поменять не во всех, а, например, только у элементов с чётными индексами, то можно сделать так:

```
for (int i=0; i<latlngs.size(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // если остаток от деления на 2 == 0
      latlngs.get(i).setTitle("my second title");
    }
}
```

Это работает потому, что вызов `latlngs.get(i)` отдаёт вам элемент с типом `MarkerData`, у которого вы можете вызывать методы этого класса.

У вас ошибка, вероятно возникает из-за путаницы со скобками.

И ещё, рекомендуется при работе со списками, в левой части использовать интерфейсный тип `List` вместо конкретного типа класса `ArrayList`, это даст вам больше гибкости в последущем сопровождении вашего кода.

То есть вместо:

```
ArrayList<MarkerData> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
```

лучше писать:

```
List<MarkerData> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Тогда, впоследствии, если вы решите вместо `ArrayList` использовать другую реализацию интерфейса `List` это будет сделать проще, чем если бы вы были привязаны к конкретному типу.

Comment: Рафаэль Благодарю за такой Точный ответ!!!

Comment: @ejik Рад, что мой ответ помог вам.